# regex for duplicate number

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to check if a string does NOT have a number more than once.

Examples:

"1..3..156" should return false.

"23..45.2." should return false.

"1.3.456.." should return true.

"5...46.28" should return true.

I am hoping to use regex for this as that is what I need the most work in compared to filtering it out with loops. I was wondering if this is possible.

I have tried the regex `/(\d)\1/` but this only gets a match if the numbers are back to back. I am trying to find a way to look ahead at rest of string as well. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Just allow other chars between the capture group and back-reference `/(\d).*\1/`

Comment: You want `if !(/(\d).*\1/.test(text)) {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the regex pattern `(\d).*\1`:

```js
function hasNoDuplicateDigit(input) {
    return !/(\d).*\1/.test(input);
}

console.log("1..3..156 => " + hasNoDuplicateDigit("1..3..156"));
console.log("23..45.2 => " + hasNoDuplicateDigit("23..45.2"));
console.log("1.3.456.. => " + hasNoDuplicateDigit("1.3.456.."));
console.log("5...46.28 => " + hasNoDuplicateDigit("5...46.28"));
```

The pattern used here matches (and captures) any single digit which is followed by that same digit at a later point in the input.

Comment: Note that `.` does not match newline characters. You can use the [`s` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags) or use [`[^]` instead of `.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes#types) if you want to include newline characters.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Wasn't even sure multiple line inputs were on the table.  We could also match `(\d)[\S\s]*\1` in this case.

Comment: I looks like OP doesn't use newline characters in their example, but future readers might. So the comment was meant as a heads up for them.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I can't believe I didn't think about adding the .* in the regex. I appreciate all of your help.